# Firefox - width: 100% not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I am building a site that works fine in both Chrome and Safari, but am having difficulties in Firefox. The applicable HTML in this issue is simple, is is just three `div`s inside of another `div`. The goal is to have one `div` positioned at the top of the parent `div`, one at the bottom, and one stretching across the remaining space:

```
                <div class="outer">
                    <div class="top">                            
                        <p>some junk here</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="middle">
                        <img src="<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($image_url)); ?>"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bottom">
                        <p>more junk</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now, the css is as follows:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}

.middle {
    background-size: 100%;
    top: 62px;
    bottom: 62px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.middle img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 95%;
    max-height: 95%;
}

.top, .bottom {
    width: 100%; /* THIS IS WHAT IS NOT WORKING */
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
}

.top {
    top: 0;
}

.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The issue is that the top and bottom `div`s are not extending to 100%. The are taking up as little space as necessary to fit their content. I have tried setting a max width on the `div`s, tried changing the display types, but nothing works. The kicker is, once I resize the window even the smallest amount, the top and bottom `div`s shoot to 100%. Strange. I am at a loss with this one so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the top and bottom `div`s' widths were not working properly was because they were set to a display type of table. Removing just that line fixed the issue.

```
.top, .bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* REMOVE: display: table; */
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.outer` DIV cannot be `display: inline-block` for this scenario. `inline-block` means to adapt to the child widths. You need to either specify an exact `width` dimension, or use `block` display property.

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    display: block; /* use BLOCK here instead of inline-block; */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Gah sorry, I have explicit widths and heights defined on the outer `div`. They are defined elsewhere. I'll update the code.

Comment: Also to clarify - I need to use inline-block as the display. Thanks for the suggestion though.